# How can I comment out certain lines in a tabular or longtable?

Tags: tables, longtable, comments

I would like to comment out all the content for "version B" in both tables. Is this possible with the usual comment-environments provided by the comment-package?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
parskip=false,
11pt,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
setspace,
blindtext,
comment,
booktabs
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{longtable}
\excludecomment{versionB}
\includecomment{versionA}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\section{Something}
Here are some words to form some random text.
1: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
2: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
3: And more words. Not really making sense.
4: Again the thing with the quick brown fox.

\begin{versionB}
Asdf.
\end{versionB}

\begin{longtable}[c]{rl}
\toprule
Words & More words\\
\midrule
\begin{versionB}
Not & Wanted\\
\end{versionB}
\begin{versionA}
The good & stuff\\
\end{versionA}
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}\\

{\centering
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\toprule
Words & More words\\
\midrule
\begin{versionB}
Not & Wanted\\
\end{versionB}
\begin{versionA}
The good & stuff\\
\end{versionA}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple option without the `comment` package: `\newif\ifversionA \versionAtrue \newcommand{\versionB}{\versionAfalse} \newcommand{\versionAonly}[1]{\ifversionA#1\fi}` then use `\versionAonly{...}` for anything you want to omit from version B. Switch to version B with `\versionB`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I know. Actually made me update the MWE, I forgot the tabular-part.

Comment: @musarithmia Thank for you the comment. I prefer using an environment-based solution.